# Lighting doesnt show in blender 2.8 render tab

Tags: blender

I cant seem to get my lighting to work in the render tab.
I have lights in it and they have a high strenght yet it doesnt show anything.

Im kinda new to blender so apologize in advance if the answer is obvious
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/57my2.png)

Comment: You might get a more useful response at https://blender.stackexchange.com/ if your questions (as it seems to be) is about _using_ the software, though I'd suggest giving a little more detail about what you've tried and what your expected result is.

Comment: It seems like rendering is stopped. Try to press blue play icon in top right.

Answer (score 0):

Bro do this open viewport shading in the top right corner beside of solid, preview, rendered and turn on scene light